# CodeIgniter - Load View from View

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

On loading the index page on my project it checks whether the user has signed up from Facebook and set a new password.

I redirect them to a view called "password" if their password is null, however I need to pass some data into the dropdown box (from the database), so I need to load the view with data

```
$data['teams'] = $this->home->teams();

if($password == 'null'){


     $this->load->view('password',$data);

}
```

Loads the view with the dropdown box correct but doesn't get rid of the old view! Is there a way to "unload" the current view?

Comment: Sounds like you've already loaded a view and you want to send someone to a different page.  Possibly create a new function in the controller and just redirect() them to the different page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your default view after the password check you should put all that code into else part of the if statement as shown below because the execution will continue from view loading and therefore there will be password view and default view outputted to browser. So, basically loading a view is not redirecting as you say in your post.

```
if($password == 'null'){
    $this->load->view('password',$data);
}
else {
    $this->load->view('default', $defaultData);
}
```